# How to centre an inserted pdf?

Tags: pdfpages, alignment

I need to insert a paper I published as an appendix in my PhD thesis. I have used the following to do so:

`\includepdf[pages=2-16, scale=1, width=\textwidth]{NRLpaper.pdf}`

This has inserted all the pages nicely, but they're not in the centre of the page and are actually eating in the margins. How do I fix that?

Comment: Add the `frame` option to see exactly what is inserted (and where…)

Comment: Are you using a document class which uses `\hoffset` and `\voffset` for a different purpose than proposed in the TeXbook?